# Proper way of saying: "The one who listens to others is the one who is listened by others"

Tags: quotes

I'm doing a presentation and one of my key point (as the one developed in [Forbes.com here](http://www.forbes.com/sites/mikemyatt/2012/02/09/why-most-leaders-need-to-shut-up-listen/#68b68ee83932)) is that to be relevant to others you have to listen them first.

I would like to say it in a compact and catchy way using twice the same verb ("listen" here but I am open to any suggestion) in order to insist on both the passive and active part of the action.

Thank you

Comment: “One who listens to others is the one who is **heard** by others,” or more simply: "To be heard, you must first listen."

Comment: Thank you, I l will go for the second one! 
I think you answered in the "comment" section because I can't find where to valid you answer

Comment: I only write a formal answer if I can provide supporting evidence.

Comment: @Mick - This wouldn't be hard to document.  Go for it!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> He who listens will be he to whom others will listen.

That would seem to satisfy your request.
Or alternatively,

> To be heard, one must first hear.

Answer (score 0):

“One who listens to others is the one who is heard by others,” or more simply: "To be heard, you must first listen."

– Mick, in comments section.

Posting this answer so this question can be "answered".

Comment: This doesn't seem to match what he requested, building the phrase around using the same verb twice?

Comment: True, but "Thank you, I l will go for the second one! I think you answered in the "comment" section because I can't find where to valid you answer – Bertinchamps"